# Spring Security PreAuthorize ROLE does not pick up JWT claim

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, token, roles

I have implemented a simple OAuth2 test app (Authorization Server, Resource Server, Client), based on [a Baeldung example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server) (Sample code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/oauth-authorization-server))

Everything works fine, but **I want to add an *additional* security contraint**:

- So far the ResourceServer verifies the Client’s `SCOPE` (by JWT inspection).
- I want the ResourceServer to also check the **`ROLE` of the user who authorized the client**.

**What I did:**

- By default the ROLE information is not as claim in the JWT, so I added it (in the Authorization Server). It now adds new claim auth (unsure if `auth` is the right keyword):

```java
  @Bean
  OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
    return context -> {
      if (context.getTokenType() == OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN) {
        Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();
        String enumeratedRoles = principal.getAuthorities().iterator().next().getAuthority();
        context.getClaims().claim("auth", enumeratedRoles);
      }
    };
  }
```

- I debugged the ResourceServer's portected method (the one invoked by client). Both, JWT and authorized.principal carry the additional claim, so far so good:

  - JWT bayload, deserialized:

```
{
   "sub":"AssortmentExtender",
   "aud":"assortment-client",
   "nbf":1689578763,
   "auth":"ROLE_ADMIN",
   "scope":[
      "assortment.write"
   ],
   "iss":"http://auth-server:9000",
   "exp":1689579063,
   "iat":1689578763
}
```

- Protected method, debug info:

```java
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
  @PutMapping("/bookstore/isbns/{isbn}")
  public void addBookToAssortment(@RequestBody BookDetailsImpl bookDetails, final @AuthenticationPrincipal
  Jwt jwt, Authentication authentication) {
// Whatever protected logic, here I debugged...
}
```

Debugger fields, for method's authentication parameter correctly shows the ROLE_ADMIN claim:

```
  name = "AssortmentExtender"
    ...
  principal = {Jwt@7362}
    headers = {Collections$UnmodifiableMap@7402\ size = 2
    claims = {Collections$UnmodifiableMap@7403} size = 8
      "sub" -> "AssortmentExtender"
      "aud" -> {ArrayList@7428} size = 1
      "nbf" -> ‹Instant@74301 #2023-07-17T07:15:33Z"
      "auth" -> "ROLE_ADMIN"
      "scope" -> {ArrayList@7434} size = 1
      "iss" -> "htto://auth-server:9000"
      "exp" -> {Instant@7406) "2023-07-17T07:20:33Z"
      "iat" -> (Instant@7405) "2023-07-17T07:15:33Z"
    tokenValue = "eyJrawQiOil3YTzNTNmOCOxYTAXLTQwNmQtYjczOCthN
    issuedAt = (Instant@7405) "2023-07-17T07:15:33Z"
    expiresAt = {Instant@74061 2023-07-17T07:20:33Z"
  credentials = {Jwt@7362}
```

**What does not work:**

- The ResourceServer's `@PreAuthorize` rejects the Client request.
- Logger says:

```
  Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: [...] with authorization manager
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager@4b97e0b0 and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false,
expressionAttribute=hasRole('ADMIN')]
```

**Summary:**

- The claim is there, JWT and principal object correctly show the ADMIN_ROLE claim.
- @PreAuthorize rejects the request anyway.

**Question:**

- Why does PreAuthorize not pick up the 'auth' claim?
- Am I just using the wrong keyword? Is `@PreAuthorize` checking something else than the principal claims?  (I've already tried various variants, including `role`, `roles`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608603/issue-with-extracting-role-claim-from-jwt-token-in-spring-api/75930588#75930588))

**EDIT:**

- From what I've found so far, the problem is that `@PreAuthorize` does not acutally access the claims, but the `authorities` extracted from the JWT structure. By default it only extracts scopes, and prefixes each entry with `SCOPE_`.
- My guess is that I somehow need to register a mechanism that does now the same for my jwt ROLES, and this seems to be possible with a custom [`JwtAuthenticationConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72226464/13805480). However, I am lost as of how to achieve this, notably since the `jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(...)` addendum for the `SecurityConfig` appears to be deprecated now.

**EDIT2**

- Based on [Sebastiaans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76703218/13805480) answer, and [this sample converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71587089/13805480), I am now able to convert the claim to an authority, using a converter:

```java
  private Converter getJwtAuthenticationConverter() {

    // create a custom JWT converter to map the "roles" from the token as granted authorities
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter =
        new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles"); // claim as JSON entry in JWT
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix(
        "ROLE_"); // prefix to be used in authority object

    // Return a new Converter object that reflects the above JWTclaim-To-Authorities rules.
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
  }
```

- However unfortunately this seems to overwrite all existing authorities from the `scope` claims.
- Based on a [github discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10439#issuecomment-952245775), I tried to write a converter that combines the existing `scope` rules with the custom `roles` claim, but unfortunatley this throws a `cast` exception at runtime:

```java
// Throws classcast exception at runtime: 
// java.util.LinkedHashSet cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken
  private Converter getDualJwtAuthenticationConverter() {

    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter scope = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    scope.setAuthorityPrefix("SCOPE_");
    scope.setAuthoritiesClaimName("scope");
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter roles = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    roles.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
    roles.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
    return new DelegatingJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(scope, roles);
  }
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is that the Security configuration `jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(whateverConverter());` wants a converter of type `<Jwt, AbstractAuthToken>`, while the `DelegatingJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` is of type `<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>>`.

So ultimately the question is how to write a converter that combines multiple JWT claims into a fused list of authorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fuse multiple JWT claims to a list of authorities.

- The trick was indeed to write a custom converter, as recommended by [@Sebastiaan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76703218/13805480).
- The solution is very close to [this proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234971/13805480) (same goal, fusing of multiple claims), although I changed the proposal to match my JWT structure.
- I also added JavaDoc comments for the implementation, to explain what actually happens in the converter code.

In essence, only two things were needed:

1. Create you own converter in a new class:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;

/**
 * This is a custom converter to extract all entries of two Jwt claims "scope" and "role". All
 * findings are prefixed with the respective "SCOPE_" and "ROLE_" prefixes, and then wrapped up as a
 * list of authorities, which can be processed by Springs SPeL in @PreAuthorize annotations. This
 * implementation is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234971/13805480
 */
public class FusedClaimConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

  // The fused converter internally fuses the outputs of two converters.
  // One component is the default converter (extracting scp/scope claim information).
  // So we create one instance of this off-the-shelf convert for later use.
  private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter defaultGrantedAuthoritiesConverter =
      new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();

  /**
   * This method provides the second component of our custom converter. It is a manual
   * implementation that searches the jwt for a custom "role" claim. If found, all entries are
   * prefixed with "ROLE_" and returned as list of authorities.
   *
   * @param jwt as the json web token to analyze for "role" claim entries.
   * @return collection of granted authorities extracted from the jwt.
   */
  private static Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractResourceRoles(final Jwt jwt) {
    ArrayList<String> resourceAccess = jwt.getClaim(
        "role"); // <- specify here whatever additional jwt claim you wish to convert to authority
    if (resourceAccess != null) {
      // Convert every entry in value list of "role" claim to an Authority
      return resourceAccess.stream().map(x -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + x))
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    // Fallback: return empty list in case the jwt has no "role" claim.
    return Collections.emptySet();
  }

  /**
   * This is the main converter method to override. In essence here we provide a custom
   * implementation that concatenates the authority lists generated from two respective conterters.
   * One is the off-the-shelf default converter that operates on the "scp"/"scope" claim. The other
   * is the converter for our custom claim.
   *
   * @param source as the json web token to inspect for claims
   * @return list of authorities extracted from token, wrapped up in AbstractAuthenticationToken
   * object.
   */
  @Override
  public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(final Jwt source) {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities =
        Stream.concat(defaultGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(source).stream(),
            extractResourceRoles(source).stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return new JwtAuthenticationToken(source, authorities);
  }
}
```

2. Register your custom converter in the ResourceServer's `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig {

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            // Whatever custom rules...
            [...]
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> {
          oauth2.jwt(jwt -> {
            jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(new FusedClaimConverter()); // <-- Here the custom converter is registered.
          });
        });

    return http.build();
  }
```

EDIT:
For completeness, I've [uploaded a well documented runnable application with this configuration on GitHub](https://github.com/m5c/spring-security-oauth).

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely an answer but hopefully enough to get you on the way a bit.

**On the topic of the JWT contents:**

We also fill an `authorities` field ourselves in the claims section of the JWT.

**On the topic of configuring the authentication converter:**

This code isn't deprecated. The API only changed a little bit.

```
http.oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> {
     resourceServer.jwt(jwt -> {
         jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(converter -> {
            // TODO: implement me
            return null; 
         });
     });
});
```

So you can actually still implement that in a non-deprecated way.

I don't know how to exactly implement that part though, since we don't use those methods and just do that ourselves instead. We do it by providing a bean of the type `AuthenticationProvider`. If you don't need anything fancy, I imagine your way will also work and might even be preferred (our code is from before the modern rewrite of the oauth2 implementation in Spring)

Comment: So I would assume the "converter" I implement here in essence accesses the non-standard JWT claims and its output then serves as extension of the regular authorities? Is this understanding correct? The implementation something as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72226464/13805480

Comment: @m5c I imagine that would work, but I don't have a lot of experience with those classes. Our authentication mechanism allows for 3 types of authentication, of which oauth2 is just one, so it's a lot more custom code in our case.

Comment: The way exposed here is a valid answer and should be accepted. In the `TODO`, you just merge the various claims you want as authorities source, with the processing you want for each (add "SCOPE_" prefix to entries in scope claim for instance or change case). You could also use ["my" starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) which auto-configures an authorities converter based on application properties.